# Alert which displays input from a text field after hitting a button

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

**Edit: Fixed thanks to the help of someone here. Updated the code to reflect what is working.**

Making a basic project for school. An "Emergency Contact" List of sorts.

4 text fields, Name, Relationship, Phone Number, and Email. Pressing a button then transfers this data to labels, then clears the textfields. I want an alert to pop up saying what the Textfield or Label's held data is.

All I can find is how to add a textfield to an alert. I do not want this. I just want to display what was entered in the text field on the alert upon button press.

It currently states the below message:

```
"Please be aware you are setting contact information for alerts to be 
sent to Contact 4."
```

but I would like it to display

```
"Please be aware you are setting contact information for alerts to be 
sent to Contact 4.
EMAIL@EMAIL.COM
407-123-4567"
```

The "email@email.com" and "407-123-4567" will be whatever the use put into the text boxes.

**Screenshots below of the example code working as intended.**
Information is entered into the text field. When the corresponding contact button is pressed, the information is passed to the labels accordingly and then it pops up in an alert.
[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wisvz.png)
[Second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6x8nc.png)

```
 @IBAction func contact4Button(_ sender: Any) {


    // Setting the information for text fields
    c4N = nameFieldtxt.text!
    c4Namelbl.text = "\(c4N!)"

    c4R = relationshipFieldtxt.text!
    c4Relationshiplbl.text = "\(c4R!)"

    c4C = contactFieldtxt.text!
    c4Contactlbl.text = "\(c4C!)"

    c4E = emailFieldtxt.text!
    c4Emaillbl.text = "\(c4E!)"

    c4lbl.text = "Contact 4"
    nameFieldtxt.text=""
    relationshipFieldtxt.text=""
    contactFieldtxt.text=""
    emailFieldtxt.text=""

    // Alert for the warning of contact alerts
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "P.H.A.B.S.", message: 
    "Please be aware you are setting contact information for alerts to be sent 
    to \(c4lbl.text!) \n \n \(c4N!) \n \(c4C!) \n \(c4E!) \n", preferredStyle: .alert)


    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: formatting would help a lot for readability

Comment: What issue are you having? Build a string containing the data you want and use that string as the alert's message.

Comment: Are you wanting to send information into the alert controller or out of it? It looks like you're wanting a form in the alert controller that sends inputs to underlying view correct?

Comment: @AquilaSagitta I've modified it a little bit. Hope it's easier to see, read, and understand what I want to do.

Comment: @rmaddy If you see I already have a bit of text displayed. I also already have the text entered into the TextField which gets input into a label. I want the Alert to be able to display the standardized text in addition to what is entered into the Textfield upon button press

Comment: @AnthonyLombardi Dunno what you are exactly asking for, but I think you are looking for this: 

`let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "P.H.A.B.S.", message: 
    "Please be aware you are setting contact information for alerts to be 
    sent to \(c4lbl.text)\n \(c4E) \n \(c4C)" , preferredStyle: .alert)`

but you need to safely unwrap these first... To be honest I wouldn't want tosee the whole application code deducting the numbers in variables and label names... Consider refactoring, but it's just other topic :)

Comment: @DominikBucher That looks to be about right. I tried something like that but it ended up giving me some errors or didn't display at all. Also, understandable. Completely novice when it comes to coding. I'm sure there are 100 better ways to do what I have above, alas, it's the novice life for me

Comment: @DominikBucher I believe I got it working as I need it! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @AnthonyLombardi No problem! :) Happy coding